# Can I bring extra baggage in qatar airways?

Tags: qatar-airways

I am travelling from Doha to Manila via qatar airways. Can I bring 2 baggage weighing in total 30kg (which is the allowed baggage) plus the 7kg handy carry or I can only bring one baggage weighing 30kg plus hand carry 7kg? If I like to bring extra one baggage how much do I need to pay?

Comment: http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/excess-baggage-rates.page

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your ticket type. You need to check it to know how many kilos is allowed for check in bag as well as your cabin bag.